# GoogleScript not marking wanted cells

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the following code to find cells that contain an integer greater than 14.

```
  var lastRow = samsara.getLastRow();
  var rangeHours = samsara.getRange(1,63,lastRow,1);  //column 63 is BK
  var hoursData = rangeHours.getDisplayValue();
  for(var j = 0; j<hoursData.length;j++){
  if(hoursData[i] > 14 ){
  samsara.getRange(j,63).setBackground("yellow");
  }
```

I use getDisplayValue because the cells contain a formula like

=if(And(BD18>0,B18>0), mround(Mod(Index(split(BJ18,"-"),1,2)-Index(split(BI18,"-"),1,2),1)*24,0.25),"")

When I run the script, none of the cells containing a number more than 14 turn yellow. See image below, Column BK is the column I am working in and there is a cell with 14.5 but it did not turn yellow.
[image]

Comment: Use getValue() instead of getDisplayValue() or cast result as number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you're using `getDisplayValue()` giving you a single cell's value, instead of `getDisplayValues()` giving you all of the values in the column.

```
function highlightHighHours() {
  var samsara = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = samsara.getLastRow();
  var rangeHours = samsara.getRange(1,63,lastRow,1);  //column 63 is BK
  var hoursData = rangeHours.getDisplayValues();
  for(var j = 0; j<hoursData.length;j++){
    if(hoursData[j] > 14 ){
      samsara.getRange(j+1,63).setBackground("yellow");
    }
  }
}
```

Then you have a few other issues:

- `i` isn't defined in `hoursData[i] > 14`. Use `j` instead.
- Since you're already selecting a single column, this isn't a big deal, but technically `hoursData[j]` is an array. So you should get the value within it by calling `hoursData[j][0]`.
- `getRange(j,63)` will select the prior row, because ranges are 1-based but arrays are 0-based. Use `getRange(j+1, 63)` instead.

Comment: I did not even see that I used [i] instead of [j]. I will implement these changes and try.